# How to rename a branch and delete the "old" master branch on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

On my Github Repo https://github.com/mainzed/labelingsystem-server/branches there are two branches. The default branch "rdf4j" is the correct one. The stale branch "master" can be deleted.

How can I safely delete the "master" branch and rename "rdf4j" to "master"?

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout rdf4j
git branch -D master # delete old master
git branch -m rdf4j master # rename to master
git push origin +master :rdf4j # force-push the new master and delete remote rdf4j
```